# Why does make -j perform better when it is passed a number larger than the number of cores available?

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have a quad-core processor with [hyper-threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).  When I use `make -j8` it is faster than `make -j4` (I read the number of cores in Java and then called `make -j<number of cores>`).

I don't understand why `make -j32` is faster than `make -j8` when I have (read in Java) just 8 cores (hyper-threading doubles the number of physical cores).  How is that possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's more to compiling than CPU speed and number of cores available: disk bandwidth and memory bandwith matter a lot too.

In your case, I imagine that each CPU HT sibling is getting roughly 4 processes to execute. As it starts one, it blocks on disk IO and moves onto the next process. The second one tries to open a second file, blocks on disk IO, and the sibling moves onto the next process. Starting four compilers before the first disk IO is ready wouldn't surprise me.

So when the first one finally read in the program source, the compiler must start hunting through directories to find the #included files. Each one requires some open() calls followed by read() calls, all of which can block, and all of which will relinquish the sibling for other processes to run.

Now multiply that by eight siblings -- each HT core will run until it blocks on memory access, at which point it'll swap over to the other sibling, and run for a while. Once the memory of the first sibling has been fetched into the cache, it is probably time for the second sibling to stall while waiting for memory.

There is an upper limit on how much faster you can get your compiles to run by using `make -j`, but twice-number-of-cpus has been a good starting point for me in the past.

Comment: Disk IO should not be an issue in caching OSs like Linux (after initial run of `make`). Threads within the same HT core would compete for cache space so benefit there is also not questionable.

Answer (score 1):

Starting more processes can still potentially give you benefits. For example, one process can use the CPU while another process on the same CPU is waiting for file